# .htaccess redirection rule for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-redirect

I have moved a WordPress blog from subfolder to a subdomain.

Previous structure : `www.sitename.com/fashion-blog`

New structure is here :
`www.blog.sitename.com`

The WordPress has been moved to the root directory of sub domain. How can I redirect visitors using `.htaccess` so that if some one visits old URLs , they will be redirected to new URLs.

For example if some one visits: 
`http://www.sitename.com/fashion-blog/some-post.html`
they should be redirected to its new URl as:
`http://blog.sitename.com/some-post.html`

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your .htaccess file

```
RedirectMatch 301 /fashion-blog/some-post.html http://blog.sitename.com/some-post.html
```

Comment: hi keyur, its not working. however its not about a single page. i want to redirect all pages. after moving the blog to new address, all post are giving us 404 errors. when i manually access these post its working. for example http://www.blog.sitename.com/posts.html